# ASP.NET MVC application becomes unresponsive after a Task completes

Tags: asp.net, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 web-application running on the .NET Framework 4.7.1.

Inside the controller's actions we call a service's method that sometimes start a new `Task` like so:

Controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    Info info = await this.someService.GetInformationAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    return this.ProcessInfo( info );
}
```

SomeService (which exists as a `static` object inside `Global.asax`):

```
private readonly Object taskLock = new Object();
private Task errorCheckerTask;

public Task<Info> GetInformationAsync()
{
    try
    {
        ...
    }
    catch( Exception ex )
    {
        this.StartErrorChecker();
    }

    return null;
}

private void StartErrorChecker()
{
    lock( this.taskLock )
    {
        if( this.errorCheckerTask == null || this.errorCheckerTask.Status >= TaskStatus.RanToCompletion )
        {
            this.errorCheckerTask = this.BeginErrorCheckerAsync( CancellationToken.None );
        }
    } 
}

private async Task BeginErrorCheckerAsync( CancellationToken ct )
{
    while( !ct.IsCancellationRequested )
    {
        Boolean ok = await DoStuff();
        if( ok ) return;
        await Task.Delay( 30 * 1000 ).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

After the `BeginErrorCheckerAsync` task starts for the first time, things seem okay - but when `BeginErrorCheckerAsync` runs for a second time then Visual Studio's `Output` window reports a bunch of threads ending and then the web-application stops responding to any new HTTP requests - all browsers just say they're waiting for a response after sending their requests.

I hit the Break button and the Visual Studio Threads window showed only a handful of threads running, none of which had any user-code in any of their stack-traces.

Importantly, no first-chance exceptions were raised or any unusual output displayed in the Output window besides the messages about threads:

> The thread 0x5440 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   The thread 0x547c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   The thread 0x5450 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   The thread 0x5474 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

I'm assuming I haven't found a bug in ASP.NET MVC - but I don't understand how my use of Tasks/`async`/`await` could make ASP.NET deadlock (assuming that's the problem). I note that nowhere in my code do I call `task.Result` or `task.Wait()` which rules-out traditional forms of async/await deadlocks, and none of the thread stack-traces are in .NET code anyway.

Comment: You haven't included the code for `DoStuff` in your question, thus you do not have an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In addition, it's not clear why you have such a convoluted process for handling an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `ConfigureAwait(false)` on controller action methods because they must run in the synchronization context.